# Jackson and Swagger - default value for Set

Tags: spring-boot, rest, jackson, swagger-ui, hashset

I wish attribute "certificados" should be initialized with empty Set "[]"

I have tried JsonSetter and also initialize attribute, but without success

[image]

"certificados" is exposed that way

[image]

Comment: How is `certificados` defined and annotated in your Java code? Please add the code to your question.

Comment: Ok, I have edited

Comment: Does `@ApiModelProperty(example="[]")` work?

Comment: @Helen it helps in fact...but in that case it came "[]" as string in Swagger when I expected []

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved using the configuration below

[image]

Comment: Please post solution in comment rather that posting image, when using image you should write the solution as text too